# how to get gcloud APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, github-actions

I'm trying to use this github-action: https://github.com/ameydev/gke-kubectl-action

- the purpose is to be able to set deployment image in k8s in gcloud in the ci-cd.

it needs `APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` from my gcloud account.

the plugin use this here: (https://github.com/ameydev/gke-kubectl-action/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L16)

```
echo "$APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" | base64 -d > /tmp/account.json
```

I have no idea what it is and how to get it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the service account json file.

Here is a link you can follow:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

You need to assign an appropriate role to a service account and download the key.

Then copy the content of the key and put it against the variable e.g. APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

Comment: which key should I copy it's content from the json file? `private_key`?

Comment: `$APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is base64 encoded key.json file. Whole file, not just one field. If you have your json file with credentials, run `cat key.json | base64` and use the output as APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. @StavAlfi

Comment: @Stavalfi : yes

Comment: each of you say thinks different. i will see what is working and let you know. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

```
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```